# Converting parallel printer switch into USB KVM switch

Tags: usb, switches, parallel-port

[cable and switch http://ibb.co/dDctkk](http://ibb.co/dDctkk)

http://ibb.co/dDOAWQ)

Quick preface, I have nothing but rudimentary EE education, only what I may call "common sense" sort of knowledge.

I have 3x serial (or parallel, actually) switches, used for printers at a now defunct call center, the entire centers' equipment which I inherited via Craigslist last summer.

Two switches are 25PDT switches in a big box and the third switch is a fancy PCB switch, shown in pictures.

I have an FTP server running in Windows 7 on one PC and Debian Jessie on a separate system, and I am getting tired of switching the USB plug when I want to switch systems, so I thought I could use the parallel switch with USB wired in to accomplish this task. All wires and all circuits have shown connections, as tested with a *-rigged circuit tester I made - - the Led lights up.

The problem is that there is no connection when I put the switch into the loop. Is anyone able and willing to help me troubleshoot?

That is about all I know to inform you with. If there is any further pertinent information, please allow me to update my question with said information.

Thank you if you have read this far, as I know I can be verbose to put it

[image][image]

Comment: Side note, this is what VNC and other remote desktop applications are for.

Comment: I use TeamViewer, but to keep it short, it doesn't work for what I intend. I had thought maybe it was the voltage in the circuit causing the issue, but your answer may just be the only approach. I shall try other methods then. Thank you.

Comment: And I hope your lines aren't tied into the lines with leds on them.

Comment: There do exists comercial USB/KVM switches. I would suggest you buy one.

Comment: If I could afford even a cheap kvm, I would do so right now, however, I am stuck with what I have for the moment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You've accepted a rather erroneous answer written by someone with a vague textbook understanding of theory but obviously lacking practical experience in its application.  While what you want to do is not recommended, there's a very real chance it will work, especially if you keep the wiring neat.  In practice people run USB, especially its lowest speed variations, through breadboards and all sorts of "improper" wiring.  It works or it doesn't or it works sometimes and not others - you get to decide if that is useful to you.

Comment: Yes well I feel I need to tread extremely cautiously around the stack exchange websites and placate everyone because of how I've been treated on them, after my very first question, which I had thought was carefully arranged, I was down voted so harshly that I received an email telling me that if I received another down voted question I would be unable to ask questions ever again.  I just don't want to get bullied off the *exchange sites.

Comment: And I do understand your are correct, I made the switch as simple as possible - female USB and two male soldered directly to a 25pdt (overkill, I know, but the only switch large enough I own) switch, and the devices I have connected periodically and without warning or provocation stop functioning. Is there maybe some way to clean up the signal? I haven't a dime to my name, but my garage is packed full of scrap electronics, which contain more parts than I shall ever use. I am able to read and write circuit diagrams (if not know the formulae for why each component is placed thus) if that helps.

Comment: @Ben getting the intermediate circuitry on the PC board out of the way by using the switches directly has already been suggested (you would have to remove them from the board or else carefully cut all associated traces).  Also make sure you are switching the keyboard and mouse directly, not a hub, as the hub will use higher speed signalling to talk to the host, and that is far more picky.

Comment: I am afraid you need to start over. First, what are you trying to switch? One USB wired keyboard (USB LS mode) to share between two USB hosts? Or you are trying to use high-speed USB devices as well? Then, we don't care where did you acquire the switch and which Debian or else is running on your hosts, but could you please draw an engineering-grade schematics of what your switch does and how did you wire it? Please show all wires, ground, VBUS, D+/D-, and how your wires possibly fork along the board.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am way to lazy to draw a proper schematic, because I do not wish to learn the software required- but here are some pictures of what is now my end product. and keep in mind, this switch DOES work for switching the USB, however it usually cuts off and stops working after some minutes until i unplug and replug it in.

Comment: @AliChen
https://s28.postimg.org/hyt3ptiyh/20170505_012610.jpg
https://s28.postimg.org/7d98dtcmx/20170505_012627.jpg
https://s28.postimg.org/yp4hf5hdl/20170505_012833.jpg

Comment: Ben, this is not what is written in your question. So, the connect/switch does work, but is flaky. Then you have the signal integrity issue due to signal pairs having out-of-whack impedance, as Asmyldof just said, the hairy random wiring won't work.

Comment: @alichen yes, the situation has indeed changed since the inception of this question, but it felt inappropriate to delete the entire question and ask the modified question, seeing as there is some very good information here and very interesting discussions, and I value each person's input, and editing my original post would have changed enough information that it would be easy to deem such as dishonest and merit a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB is a system that uses what we call "differential pairs", because it is a very high speed system.

A differential pair is designed to be coupled together at a very specific coupling. Like in UTP cables, the signal wires are put into the cable at a very specific recipe, so that the impedance seen by signals of those data wires fits an exact specification.

Once that impedance changes more than 10% over more than a very small section problems occur with the signals. They start echoing and bouncing up and down. It'll be like trying to communicate a very delicate series of instructions in the most echo-y room you can imagine.

Adding a few loops of wires or such very likely creates a deviation of more than 50% at a local point. That point will be the hard brick wall in my analogy that is the surface those signals echo against/from.

If you don't know specific recipes for keeping USB signals perfectly coupled, or close enough to it, you'll create such perfect brick walls that nothing can use your system to properly communicate, because all they will hear is echoes.

Comment: The poster is talking about the lowest speed class of USB device however, which means a lot more tolerance for bad cabling than trying to access a flash drive or hard drive at USB 2 high speed rates or more would likely have.

Comment: if you cut the PCB traces ans solder the usb wires directly to the switches you have a chance that it might work,

Comment: I do also have the two 25pdt physical switches, but soldering the cables directly to that hasn't worked either. I must be doing something wrong. I suppose I should test each solder point individually.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you stand in a perfectly echoing chamber, you'll find it's extremely hard to properly talk at all. Sure USB 1.0 is a bit more forgiving, but it's not a world of difference. Reflection is still reflection and once the signal encounters close enough to perfect reflection it might as well be a a morse code, you'll not get it out properly anymore. Apart from that if devices identify as a certain protocol through their resistors, it'll soon default to minimum 1.1 or other higher standards and then all bets are off anyway.

Comment: You are mistaken on more levels than you realize. You won't get perfect reflection from sloppy wiring impedance discontinuities as long as there is continuity.  But at the low data rates, even heavy reflections can often be tolerated if the line length is short in terms of the symbol rate.   Next, any compliant USB host must accept that low-speed peripherals **cannot** run faster and not attempt to increase the data rate (though this does point to using a hub upstream of the improved wiring, not downstream).  While improvised wiring is not *recommended* there's a good chance it will work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Don't start reading into things. I'm not saying all edits to all cables will always create perfect reflection, nor did I say this was a case of perfect reflections, nor did I say an USB2 host cannot talk at USB1 communications speeds. But when a host and a device together decide through initial signalling they will talk at USB2.0 levels either can discontinue rather than scale back when there's too many errors. The same goes for out-of-limits SOF jitter, it's perfectly acceptable to hard discontinue the link within <=2.0 standards when deformations cause SOF jitter.

Comment: So while it may work, and there are ways to make it work when it doesn't, it's not helpful to start a discussion about what could work or could not work without full knowledge of the negotiation steps hardware takes, to which standards the devices operate and to which extend they do so correctly, or provide a beginner with bread-crumbs of hope, when in fact chances of it never working with a specific set of devices and/or modifications are as real as chances it can be made to operate properly without ever having problems. If not better.

Comment: Not to mention these KVM switches are designed with hardly any thought to traces or lengths, so "mismatches" of as much as 100mm are not at all uncommon, nor are un-terminated branches that go to uninstalled extra options that may extend equally far or further, where the 1.0 guideline specifies a mismatch of 3.81mm or less for signal pairs.

Comment: "But when a host and a device together decide through initial signalling they will talk at USB2.0 levels" **if you understood anything at all about USB**, you would realize that a low speed device will only *ever* **talk at low speed**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And this KVM makes all devices suddenly USB 1.0, yes? That's what 1980's parallel port KVM switches are known for, I suppose. You are thanked for your pointless pedantry on things _I have seen happen while inspecting USB2.0 busses for reviewing device behaviours, specially cheap mice and keyboards_, but this answer is now nicely confusing to the beginners most likely to find it.